# Chrome Extension Button Lighting Up without being clicked on?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible for a Chrome extension button (to the right of the browser address bar) to change states depending on logic based on the URL? (i.e., not being clicked on, but detects URL X, and "lights up")

Answer (score 1):

With Browser Actions you can use either [`c.b.setIcon`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon) or, [`c.b.setBadgeText`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeText) and [`c.b.setBadgeBackgroundColor`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeBackgroundColor). Or, use [Page Actions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html) instead.

With this methods you can change the visual aspect of your UI Actions. But, what you can't do is opening any popup programatically.

Comment: Obviously, `c.b.` = `chrome.browserAction`. And for "logic based on the URL", see the [`chrome.tabs.*` events](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#global-events): `onActivated` and `onUpdated`.